# How do I access azure storage $logs

Tags: azure

In the Azure Portal, I've created blob storage as follows:

http://mymedia.blob.core.windows.net/

I've enabled logging by going to mymedia > configure > logging and enabling it.

Unfortunately when I go to:

http://mymedia.blob.core.windows.net/$logs

I get a "resource not found error".

So my question is this. Once I've enabled logging for storage, how do actually access it? :/

Cheers

Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the $logs container is public by default. Can you use a tool like [Cerebrata's Azure Management Studio](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-management-studio/introduction) to open your storage account and view the $logs container?

They won't be under "Blob Containers" node but under "Storage Analytics" --> "Raw Data" node as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also spent some time looking for it. 
It seems that:

- the $logs container does not show up in the online Azure Portal
- the $logs container does also not show in in the Visual Studio (2015) Cloud Explorer
- But it **does** show up in the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer tool

Answer (score 0):

Cerebrata's tools are great, or for some free options check out the following:

Azure Storage Explorer 5.  http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/

Azure Explorer. http://www.cerebrata.com/labs/azure-explorer

Answer (score 0):

Another tool to go through Azure storage logs is CloudVyzor LogPad, now in beta. Comparing to Storage Explorer, you can actually search through there logs. This video explains it in details: https://youtu.be/q8el9e71jIE